# Is it possible to prevent MSBuild printing colourized output

Tags: msbuild, console

I've got my windows shell configured as displaying black text on a white background. This makes it almost impossible to read the default msbuild output due to the very pale colours (especially the yellow warnings).

Therefore I'd like to try one of the following, but I can't work out if it is possible.

1. I'd like to set a global setting to permanently turn off colourized output in msbuild; or
2. If (1) isn't possible is it possible to turn this output per-invocation (e.g. with command line arguments).

Does anyone know how to do one of the above?

Comment: Note this is somewhat a duplicate/related question to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9523644/21567). I wouldn't argue for closing it a such, but you might want to have a look at the other one as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MSBuild 4.0** this is possible using the `/consoleloggerparameters` or `/clp` switch:

```
msbuild C:\some_path\your.sln /clp:disableconsolecolor
```

---

Alternatively, for previous MSBuild engines, this is possible using **PowerShell**:

[`Out-Host`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347620.aspx) will display the default color:

```
Powershell -Command "msbuild C:\some_path\your.sln | out-host"
```

[`Write-Host`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347596.aspx) will let you customize the colors:

```
Powershell -Command "msbuild C:\some_path\your.sln | write-host -foreground "white""
```

Comment: Is it possible to disable output at all? But from <Target><MSBuild/> </>

Answer (score 0):

To completely disable colors use the `/clp:disableconsolecolor` option when invoking `MSBuild.exe` (for more information on the `/clp` option run `MSBuild.exe /?`).

**Update** as @KMoraz has commented, and updated his answer to, this only works with MSBuild 4.0 onwards.

If you want to disable color output you can also use the following (which will **not** work with MSBuild 4.0):

```
MSBuild.exe arguments > CON 2>&1
```

This got me curious ;-) so here is one more option that should work with all versions of MSBuild.exe and doesn't rely on `CON` redirection:

```
MSBuild.exe arguments 2>&1| findstr /r ".*"
```

Basically, what happens is that all lines of output are piped through `findstr.exe` since that uses a pattern to match "everything", all lines are simply output again, but loosing their attributes (color) information. In my tests the `2>&1` (redirect stderr to stdout) was not really necessary, as it looks MSBuild doesn't output any (colored) messages to stderr, but I added it for good measure.