# Can colors used in default MSBUILD logger be modified?

Tags: logging, powershell, msbuild, colors, console

The default MSBuild logger does nice color-coding of output lines in the console window - if you happen to use the default black background for console windows.  I find using black text on gray background in console windows to be easier on my eyes.  (black on white is too bright.)

When running MSBUILD for our projects, the output comes out a now-hard-to-read cyan on gray for some lines.  The yellow and red lines aren't as bad.

Is there a way to customize the colors used by the default MSBUILD logger?
Perhaps tweaking some XML file in the VS2010 installed files? (We're using VS2010.)

I found the MSBUILD parameter "consoleloggerparameters" but it doesn't appear to offer such a feature.

Are there third-party custom loggers available that might allow such customization or is writing my own custom logger the only option? (We could, but time to do so is hard to come by.)

Comment: Is using PowerShell an option? [Linked](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9513340/147211)

Comment: Possibly. How would that work for this? Some way to modify or do a color shift ("make all cyan output to the console be blue"?)

Comment: I've posted my shot at this. PowerShell scripters can do better I assume.

Answer (score 2):

The colors are basically hardcoded. What you can do out of the box, with MSBuild 4.0, is completely disable colors using the `/clp:disableconsolecolor` option when invoking `MSBuild.exe` (for more information on the `/clp` option run `MSBuild.exe /?`). With older MSBuild versions you can use `MSBuild.exe arguments 2>&1| findstr /r ".*"`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9529246/21567) answer for more details.

If you want to have different colors, you need to implement your [own (console) logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171471.aspx), which is not too hard, and use that (`/logger:` option, combined with `/noconsolelogger` to turn off the default console logger).

Comment: Thanks.  I was afraid of that.  (But not everyone likes black console windows ... :)   Maybe in a future version.  I do like the colored output, so I'd prefer not to disable it, just change it.  I'll try KMoraz's powershell script and see how that works for me.

Comment: The example to write your own logger looks understandable, I'll have to look at that too. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Using **PowerShell**, I suppose PS enthusiasts can provide a better script:

```
#
# Run MSBuild With Custom Color.ps1
#
msbuild C:\some_path\your.sln | foreach-object -process  { 
    switch ($_){
        { $_.tolower().contains("warning")} {Write-Host $_ -foregroundColor DarkBlue}
        { $_.tolower().contains("error")} {Write-Host $_ -foregroundColor DarkRed}  
        default {Write-Host $_ -foregroundColor Black}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, KMoraz, I'll try it out.

Comment: The switch cases need break statements.