# Color console output in C++ via msbuild exec

Tags: c++, msbuild, console-application, windows-console

**Problem**

It was easy for me to figure out a method for setting console colors in C++ using windows.h and std::cout.  One such method is shown here:

```
HANDLE stdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); //get handle of console
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO bufferInfo;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(stdout, &bufferInfo); //save current color scheme
SetConsoleTextAttribute(stdout, 0x4); //change console color
std::cout << "This is red text" << std::endl; 
SetConsoleTextAttribute(stdout, bufferInfo.wAttributes); //restore old colors
```

Sure enough, when I run my program from a console window, the colors change as expected.  The problem is, when this is run from an msbuild script, I use exec:

```
<Exec Command="myExecutable.exe" />
```

When run from the msbuild script, the colors are not affected by the program.  The text still outputs in the call to std::cout, but it's just the normal console window colors.

---

**Hypothesis**

My guess is that the call to exec writes to stdout via different handle than STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE.  Either that, or the msbuild exec sets its own console attributes.  I've tried getting the parent console, but haven't had any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523644/can-colors-used-in-default-msbuild-logger-be-modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely thing is that MSBuild connects your executable to a pipe. When you write something to a pipe MSBuild reads it from the other end, then it may do some processing: like writing to screen, to logs, etc... The issue is that you cannot transfer colors through a pipe. In fact you can check that your `stdout` handle is not a console buffer using `GetFileType`, which will return `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` for a console but `FILE_TYPE_PIPE` if my hypothesis is correct. You also should check whether your console function calls succeeded.

Comment: Bingo!  Calling GetFileType on the stdout handle returned FILE_TYPE_PIPE.  To be clear, then, is there no way to set colors in a pipe?

Comment: @Kirby: no. It is like a file in this aspect: just a stream of binary data.